# Twilio: Uncaught Error: Wrong number of segments

Tags: twilio

I was having some Twilio connectivity issues and thought I'd write a standalone script to reproduce the problem so that I could submit a ticket with Twilio. Unfortunately, I'm having some difficulty doing so.

Here's what I have:

```
<script src="https://sdk.twilio.com/js/taskrouter/v1.21/taskrouter.min.js"></script>
<script>
var worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker('...', true);
worker.on('error', function(error) {
    alert(error.code + ' ' + error.length);
});
</script>
```

When I run this code I get a `Uncaught Error: Wrong number of segments` error in the JS console.

I prob need to pass the API Token, Account SID, Auth token and app sid to Twilio but it's not clear to me how to do that. Are the Twilio PHP API libraries supposed to generate some JS that'll authenticate against Twilio?

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a `Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker` the first argument you need to supply is a Capability Token. A Capability Token is a JSON Web Token (JWT) that you generate on your server and sign it with your Auth Token.

The [instructions for how to construct a Capability Token for a TaskRouter Worker](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/constructing-jwts) are in the documentation. Each of the Twilio server side helper libraries have functions for generating these tokens. You can see examples of generating a token on this page about [managing workers in the browser](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/worker).

Comment: It's not clear to me from that documentation how to get that JS to work. I tried running https://pastebin.com/ihEpQ1NN on a LAMP server. It doesn't appear that the PHP code output anything. Like superficially it seems like it might echo out JS code that performs the authentication but it turns out that it isn't. What am I doing wrong?